# Folder to exchange files between Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have two Azure Functions. The first one generates one big template file and stores it in `d:\local` folder.

After that this function sends about 10 POST requests to another Azure Function with some parameters.
The function, that received the POST request launches, copies this template file and processes it with the passed parameters.

Although the template file generated successfully in the first function,  I get `file not found` error, when I try to copy that template file in the second function. I assume I have to use another folder, instead of `d\local`.

What folder should I use to exchange files between Azure Functions?

`d:\home` or something else ?

Comment: Are you using the consumption plan or hosting functions on your own app service plan?

Comment: I am using the premium v1 plan. But does it affect on the issue I've reported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely happening because your function apps are spun up on different servers. Regardless of the why, you should treat cloud serverless offerings such as functions as stateless and use a service such as a storage account or (if the docs are small) service bus to exchange payloads.

Have a look at the [claim check pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/claim-check), which sounds like an appropriate solution for your use case.

Comment: thank you, Josh. I will check that article.